# Validation of Name in EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application I have field name. It works perfect if field contain digits or .,?... characters but when I enter usman(space)shafi it gives error. My statement take space as invalid character between two words. Please can anyone tell me how to make it work. Thanks

here is the code

```
   if(!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", textname.getText().toString().trim())){

         textname.setError("Invalid Characters");

     }
    // if(!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z]+", textkin.getText().toString().trim())){

  //     textkin.setError("Invalid Characters");

    // }");
```

Comment: could you try this "^/s^[a-zA-Z]+$/s"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the space to your regular expresion:

```
    if(!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z ]+", textname.getText().toString().trim())){

         textname.setError("Invalid Characters");

     }
```

Answer (score 0):

If it would be just a one white space inside you can try something like this:

```
text = textname.getText().toString().trim();
string[] txtSplt = text.split(" ");

text = "";
foreach (string s : txtSplt)
{
    text += s;
}
```

Then you can proceed with checking the condition without changing your regex.

Answer (score 0):

DO this by this way. Your problem will be solved.

```
    String regex = "([A-Z a-z]+)";
    Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(textname.getText().toString());

    if(!matcher1.matches()){
          textname.setError("Invalid Characters");
    }
```